# variable in shell script, is it an array?

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7

My code :

```
 SITE27=`python2.7 -c "import site; print site.getsitepackages()"`
 errInfo27="$?"

echo $SITE27

if [ $errInfo27 -eq 0 ]; then

case ${SITE27} in
    *\ * ) echo "VAR=$VAR has at least one space char";

 ;;
    * ) echo "VAR=$VAR has no space chars" ;;
esac

fi
```

Then for echo $SITE27, I get:

```
['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

How do I just extract the last path which is /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages ?

Thank you very much.
LJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SITE27=$(python2.7 -c "import site; print site.getsitepackages()[-1]")
```

Get last element of the list  using `[-1]`: `site.getsitepackages()[-1]`

Comment: Thank you. but if I only have one path, [-1] will just give me 's' . For more than one path, it works.

Comment: You really should avoid backticks. Always use `$()` instead.

Comment: If you are returning a list with just one element `[-1]` will output that element as it is still the last element in the list.